# storyboard constraints (Xcode)

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, size, constraints

I'm new to programming and I'm trying to work with Xcode. I have no experience. I'm trying to make an app with Xcode. I'm done with the code, the only issue i have is with the storyboard constraints. I need some one who can help me to set them up.

So, i have 28 buttons as you can see in the picture, I want to keep the size of 65x65 pixels. that means that the distance between them should vary in different device sizes(4inch, 4.7inch and 5.5inch). i also should mention that i want it to be only in portrait view and only for iPhone.i hope someone can help because I'm to noob for this, I've searched a lot on the internet but I'm not able to do it.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## UIStackView (iOS 9+)

UIStackView was introduced in iOS 9, which is very useful in your case.

**Edit**: Before getting started, make sure to have size classes to be `w Any, h Any`, this will make thing easier.

1. To use this, search `UIStackView` in your utility panel.

[image]

2. Drag an drop a `Vertical Stack View` on the view of your view controller and set the constraints so it spans the whole screen.

[image]

3. Select the stack view we just placed and set the distribution to `Fill Equally`.

[image]

4. Drag and drop a `Horizontal Stack View` onto the vertical one.
5. Select the horizontal one and set the distribution to `Fill Equally`.
6. Place your buttons in the `Horizontal Stack View`.

[image]

7. Copy and paste the horizontal stack view multiple times based on number of rows you want.

[image]

That's it.

You can control the buttons' background images to make it smaller (65px), or you can place a view as its' parent then align horizontally/vertically to place it to the center, like this:

[image]

## Orientation

If you'd like to lock the orientation throughout the app, go to the settings of your project.

[image]

## Sample project

I made a sample project for this question, you can check it out here: https://github.com/cyhsutw/UIStackView-example

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help! I tried to make it the way you showed here, but somehow it didn't turn out right. You can see in the pictures. I also downloaded your project from github and it had the same issue. http://s24.postimg.org/gzpebqapx/Bildschirmfoto_2016_04_17_um_16_06_46.png  and  http://s22.postimg.org/4ej518bip/Bildschirmfoto_2016_04_17_um_16_09_37.png  and its weird that the storyboard preview shows something different than the simulator.

Comment: Sorry for making a dumb mistake. The issue was about the size classes, looks like the constraints were set for specific size classes, not all size classes. To make the constraints are installed for all size classes, make sure this option is checked http://imgur.com/ErSr2te. 

I've update the sample project, would you mind checking it out again?

Comment: Now i have exactly what i wanted, thank you so much!

Comment: Can you please check out my new post?